# alguien sabe porque no aparece la barra apostillada cuando uso la formula position: fixed;?

Tags: position

estoy comenzando a aprender html y CSS pero tengo un problema con la etiqueta **position: fixed;** pues al poner esta acción, guardar y al poner a rodar el código en cualquier navegador no me aparece la icono ajustado a la pagina (el icono que tiene que estar intacto al hacer scroll) no se si es la configuración de mi VSC, pero estoy siguiendo los pasos de un youtuber y repito las mismas acciones que el pero a mi no me sale. añado parte del codigo, alguien sabe la posible razón y solucion?

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: "roboto", sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
}

/*------Header------*/

header {
    position: fixed, bottom 40px; right: 40px;
    height: 60px;
    right: 15;
    background-color: #e76a05;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Pizzeria</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.ccs">
    
</head>
<body>
    <header><a href="inder.Html">PIZZERIA</a>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#presentation">Inicio</a></li>
                <li><a href="#about">Sobre nosotros</a></li>
                <li><a href="#menu">Menu</a></li>
                <li><a href="#reservation">Reservas</a></li>
    
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
```

Comment: No termino de entender tu pregunta, ¿puedes ser mas claro por favor?

Comment: No puedo entender que quieres lograr resolver.

Comment: *no me aparece la icono ajustado a la pagina (el icono que tiene que estar intacto al hacer scroll)* ¿cuál ícono?

Comment: estoy tratando de hacer una barra ajustada a la parte superior de la pantalla y estoy usando la opcion position: fixed; como se ve en el codigo pero no me aparece nada cuando le doy run en el navegador @BetaM